# Why doesn't Python's len(readlines) equal Bash's 'wc -l' command?

Tags: python, bash

For some large file,

```
lines_a = len(fa.readlines())
print(lines_a)
```

And for Bash (on Mac):

```
wc -l
```

the result are different!

What is the possible reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wc -l` prints the [number of newlines](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) in input. In other words, its definition of "line" in "line count" requires the line to end with a newline, and is actually [defined by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/1600898).

This definition of line can yield surprising behavior if the last line in your file does not end with a newline. Despite such line being displayed in text editors and pagers just fine, `wc` will not count it as a line. For example:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | wc -l
2
$ printf 'foo\nbar' | wc -l
1
```

Python's `readlines()` method, on the other hand, is designed to provide the data in the file so that it can be perfectly reconstructed. For that reason, it provides each line *with* the final newline, and the last non-empty line as-is (with or without the final newline). For the above example, it returns lists `["foo\n", "bar\n"]` and `["foo\n", "bar"]` respectively, both of length two:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar' | python -c 'import sys; print len(sys.stdin.readlines())'
2
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | python -c 'import sys; print len(sys.stdin.readlines())'
2
```

Comment: your give me a reasonable explanation, but I got a big file, millions of line, the different results from the "wc -f " and "len(readlines())"  ,however, I check this file by a script, each line contains just one '\n' at the end of the line, so I guess there must be another reason, do you have any more idea?

Comment: or maybe I should ask, Is there a way in python that treat the such a line like "aaa\nbbb" as just one line?

Comment: @AndyYuan Sorry, I don't know what `wc -f` does. Also, if the file is so big, maybe it is being written to while `wc` is operating, which could explain the difference.

Comment: @ user4815162342 sorry for my mistake, it should be 'wc -l', my question is  whether python has a function to take the such a line like "aaa\nbbb\n" as just one line

Comment: @AndyYuan "aaa\nbbb\n" is two lines. If you want to "take it as one line", how do you know when to stop reading it? Python file objects have a `read()` method that return the whole file contents as a string; perhaps you can use that, and then split the resulting string as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Just mention that I met similar problem when I was doing machine translation task. The main reason that the line number is not right, maybe because you have not open the file in 'b' mode.
So try to

```
with open('some file', 'rb') as f:
    print(len(f.readlines()))
```

You will get the same number as `wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if you have \r in your text file.

> When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal
> newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or
> '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to
> the caller.

^ from python [textiowrapper documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)